# Using indicator constraint with two variables

Tags: gurobi, indicator-constraints, gurobipy

I want to use the sum of two binary decision variables (when their sum equals to one) as the condition of Model.AddGenConstrIndicator https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_agc_indicator.html, however, it seems to be impossible, e.g. for the minimal code below which reflects the relevant part of my real problem trying the following:

```
import gurobipy as gp

model = gp.Model()

x = model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name="x")
y = model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name="y")

z = model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="z")

model.update()
constr = model.addConstr((x + y == 1) >> (z <= 20))

model.setObjective(z, gp.GRB.MAXIMIZE)

# Solve the model
model.optimize()
```

Will result in the following error:

```
    constr = model.addConstr((x + y == 1) >> (z <= 20))
  File "src/gurobipy/model.pxi", line 3632, in gurobipy.Model.addConstr
gurobipy.GurobiError: Indicator constraints can only be triggered by a single binary variable at a given value
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/how-to-enforce-logical-implication-sum-j-a-j-x-j-le-b-implies-sum-j-c-j-x-j for a general approach for such generalized indicator constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to enforce $x+y=1 \implies z \le 20$.  Introduce a new binary variable $w$ and enforce
\begin{align}
x+y = 1 &\implies w = 1 \tag1\label1\\
w = 1 &\implies z \le 20 \tag2\label2\\
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{2} is already an indicator constraint.
The contrapositive of \eqref{1} is $w \not= 1 \implies x+y \not= 1$,
which you can rewrite as an indicator constraint
$$w = 0 \implies x+y = 2v \tag3\label3,$$
where $v$ is a binary variable.

Alternatively, you can rewrite \eqref{1} in conjunctive normal form to somewhat automatically derive linear constraints:
$$
((x \land \lnot y) \lor (\lnot x \land y)) \implies w \\
\lnot ((x \land \lnot y) \lor (\lnot x \land y)) \lor w \\
(\lnot (x \land \lnot y) \land \lnot (\lnot x \land y)) \lor w \\
((\lnot x \lor y) \land (x \lor \lnot y)) \lor w \\
(\lnot x \lor y \lor w) \land (x \lor \lnot y \lor w) \\
(1 - x + y + w \ge 1) \land (x + 1 - y + w \ge 1) \\
(w \ge x - y) \land (w \ge y - x)
$$

Comment: You could also introduce two new variables and one linear constraint. E.g. $x + y = 2 * v + w$. Then $w$ is your indicator for $z <= 20$.

Comment: @user1502040 will work if $v$ is nonnegative integer.

Comment: @Sutanu yes, I should have said 2 binary variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need in a code is actually something like:
(The first constraint actually comes from my last comment)

```
model = gp.Model()

x = model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name="x")
y = model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name="y")
w = model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.INTEGER, name="w")

z = model.addVar(lb=0, ub=20, vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="z")

constr = model.addConstr(x + y >= 1 - w)
constr = model.addConstr((w == 1) >> (z <= 20))
model.setObjective(z, gp.GRB.MAXIMIZE)


# Solve the model
model.update()
model.optimize()
```

---

```
Optimize a model with 1 rows, 4 columns and 3 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0xcf4a20b1
Model has 1 general constraint
Variable types: 1 continuous, 3 integer (2 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range  [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 2e+01]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 1e+00]
  GenCon rhs range [2e+01, 2e+01]
  GenCon coe range [1e+00, 1e+00]
Found heuristic solution: objective 20.0000000

Explored 0 nodes (0 simplex iterations) in 0.01 seconds (0.00 work units)
Thread count was 1 (of 2 available processors)

Solution count 1: 20 

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 2.000000000000e+01, best bound 2.000000000000e+01, gap 0.0000%
```

Also, as the second attempt I try to use two indicator variables as:

$$ w_{1}=1 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad x+y=1$$
$$ w_{2}=1 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad z\leq 20$$
$$ w_{1}=1 \implies w_{2}=1$$

The linearization of the constraints would be:
$$ w_{1}=1 \implies (x+y=1) $$
$$ \lnot(w_{1}) \lor ((x \land \lnot y) \lor (\lnot x \land y)) $$
$$ ((1-w_{1}) \lor x \lor \lnot y)) \land ((1-w) \lor \lnot x \lor y)) $$
$$ ((1-w_{1}) + x + (1-y) \land ((1-w) + (1-x) + y)) \quad (1) $$
$$ (x+y=1) \implies w_{1}=1 $$
$$ (1 - x + y + w \ge 1) \land (x + 1 - y + w \ge 1) \quad \text{from Rob's answer} \quad (2) $$
$$ w_{2}=1 \Longleftrightarrow z\leq 20$$
$$ z + (UB+\epsilon)w_{2} \geq (UB+\epsilon) \quad (3)$$
$$ w_{1} \leq w_{2} \quad (4)$$

Comment: The $x+y=w$ constraint is too restrictive because it prevents $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks. $x+y$ should be equal to one that one of $x$ or $y$ would be one. As the upper bound on the constraint is one I defined a binary variable to that. It also would be by setting $w$ up as a integer number.

Comment: In the original problem, $x+y$ can take three values ($0,1,2$), but your formulation disallows $x+y=2$.

Comment: @RobPratt, would you please, say how it takes the value of 2? Is there any constraint except $x+y=1$?

Comment: Because $x$ and $y$ are binary, there are four possible cases for $(x,y)$.  In the two cases where $x+y=1$, the requirement is that $z \le 20$.  In the other two cases $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, there is no restriction on $z$.

Comment: @RobPratt, you cheat me!! I got you mean but You answer so fast.

Comment: Now, I can understand the idea. Constraint x+y =1 in the logical sense is different from its behave in the static modeling. We need to check all of possible solution. Thanks. 

Comment: @RobPratt, can I use $2w$ instead of $w$ In the RHS to enumerate all feasible solution?

Comment: No, $x+y=2w$ would cut off the two solutions with $x+y=1$.

Comment: @RobPratt, Thanks. Based on your $4$th comment, there exist four combinations and three possible feasible solutions for $x+y$. $\{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$ combinations respectively, and $\{0,1,2\}$ feasible solution space. I think we need to change the $x+y$ into $x+y\geq 1-w$ to take all of the feasible solutions. Actually, it depends on the value of the variable $w$. May I have your insight?

Comment: No, $x+y \ge 1-w$ does not work because it allows $(x,y,w)=(1,1,1)$ and disallows $(x,y,w)=(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks. I will ask an independent question for that.

Comment: @RobPratt, please, see this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4654707/595412).