# How to enforce logical implication $\sum_j a_j x_j \le b \implies \sum_j c_j x_j \le d$

Tags: linearization, logical-constraints, indicator-constraints

Some modeling languages and solvers support indicator constraints of the form $$y=\hat{y} \implies \sum_j a_j x_j \le b,$$ where $y$ is a binary decision variable and $\hat{y}\in\{0,1\}$ is a constant.  How do I enforce a more general logical implication
$$\sum_j a_j x_j \le b \implies \sum_j c_j x_j \le d?$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this by introducing a binary decision variable and splitting into two implications:
\begin{align}
\sum_j a_j x_j \le b &\implies y = 1 \tag1\label1 \\
y = 1 &\implies \sum_j c_j x_j \le d \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{2} is already an indicator constraint.
To rewrite \eqref{1} as an indicator constraint, use its contrapositive
$$y = 0 \implies \sum_j a_j x_j > b,$$
which you can model as
$$y = 0 \implies \sum_j a_j x_j \ge b + \epsilon$$
for some small constant tolerance $\epsilon > 0$.  If $\sum_j a_j x_j$ and $b$ are integer-valued, you can take $\epsilon=1$.

Now either use the indicator constraints directly or linearize via big-M:
\begin{align}
b + \epsilon - \sum_j a_j x_j &\le M_1 y \\
\sum_j c_j x_j - d &\le M_2 (1-y)
\end{align}