# How to model the following Constraint

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, logical-constraints, integer-variable

I would like to model the following:

$B \le \alpha \implies \sum_i W(i) \ge \beta$, where $B$ a continuous variable, $W(i)$ binary variables, $\alpha$ a real constant number, $\beta$ an integer constant number

I could do this by introducing a new binary variable $Z$ and requiring

$B \le \alpha \implies Z = 1$ and $Z =1 \implies \sum_i W(i) \ge \beta$

My question is, is there a possibility of avoiding the introduction of $Z$?

Comment: Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/how-to-enforce-logical-implication-sum-j-a-j-x-j-le-b-implies-sum-j-c-j-x-j

Comment: Here the constraint $\sum_i W(i) \ge \beta $ is an all integer constraint. Could this somehow avoid the introduction of $Z$?

Comment: Dear @RobPratt, in a case, where one of $w_i$ is equal to one, then $B \leq \alpha \implies w = 1$. That can be linearized without any more binary variables. Would you say, does not any general procedure exist to do that?

Comment: I should state that $1 \le \beta \le \lvert I \rvert, i \in I$

Comment: Do you also have bounds on $B$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha$ is not a variable, it is a constant real number, so $\alpha$ bounds $B$.

Comment: Still, do you have a range on its values, like you have for the constant $\beta$? Also do you have bounds on $B$?

Comment: $0.0 \le B \le 100.0$. I would like to build the constraints for the following values of $\alpha$  $1.0, 21.0, 41.0, 61.0, 81.0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in [How to enforce logical implication $\sum_j a_j x_j \le b \implies \sum_j c_j x_j \le d$](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/how-to-enforce-logical-implication-sum-j-a-j-x-j-le-b-implies-sum-j-c-j-x-j), (temporarily) introduce constant $\epsilon>0$ and binary variable $Z$, and impose linear big-M constraints
\begin{align}
\alpha + \epsilon - B &\le (\alpha + \epsilon - 0) Z \tag1\label1 \\
\beta - \sum_i W_i &\le (\beta - 0) (1-Z) \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Now eliminate $Z$ by multiplying \eqref{1} by $\beta$ and \eqref{2} by $\alpha + \epsilon$ and adding them up to obtain the valid inequality
$$\beta(\alpha + \epsilon - B) + (\alpha + \epsilon)\left(\beta - \sum_i W_i\right) 
\le \beta(\alpha + \epsilon) Z + (\alpha + \epsilon) \beta (1-Z),$$
which simplifies to
$$B + \frac{\alpha + \epsilon}{\beta}\sum_i W_i \ge \alpha + \epsilon. \tag3\label3$$

But this is too weak unless $B=0$ or $\sum_i W_i = 0$.  The original disjunction $$B \ge \alpha + \epsilon \lor \sum_i W_i \ge \beta$$ is nonconvex, and \eqref{3} is a convex relaxation.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob . I will implement it and see.