Disjunctive bidirectional implications between two pairs of Non-negative Continuous or Integer Variables
Say for instance, I have four non-negative continuous or integer variables, $x$, $y$, $a$, $b$. I would like to ask about the constraints representing the following implications, whereby at any one time, only one of the three bidirectional implications is True.:
($x \lt y \iff a \lt b$) $\lor$ ($y \lt x \iff b \lt a$) $\lor$ ($0 \le 0 \iff 0 \le 0$)

Your proposition is always true because it is of the form $P \lor (Q \iff Q)$.

Sorry for the vacuous expression, I meant it to be a disjunction, i.e. at any one time, only one of the three bidirectional implications is True.

But the last one is always true.

@Mike, what exactly do you mean by $(0 \leq 0 \iff 0 \leq 0)$? (As Rob pointed this out it always would be true).

Sorry for the confusion .I meant to say that there are possibilities whereby in x<y and x can be 0, while y is positive thus making 0<y where x<0 can never be possible as both x and y must be non-negative. Thus, there is a need for the third distinction where 0<=0 as both x and y can be zero concurrently.

The three disjunctions are the three possibilities for the values of the decision variable pairs that arise in my problem.

0<=0 iff 0<=0 arises when say certain facilities are not used, thus setting their production to zero  Thus if both facilities A and B have 0 utilization, it implies that both have 0 production. On the other hand, if facilitiy A had less utilization than facility B, under the same production rate, it is implies that facilities A has less output than facilitiy B and vice-versa

Apologies, I guess I must have wrote the third disjunction incorrectly.

The issue is that both x and y can never be equal when positive except when both are 0 or when one is positive and the other is 0

@Mike, for the last part, do you try $(x \geq \epsilon \land y \geq \epsilon) \implies (x \neq y)$?

I removed ϵ from the expression second last expression from this link https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/how-to-enforce-logical-implication-sum-j-a-j-x-j-le-b-implies-sum-j-c-j-x-j, it seems valid for 0<=0 too. Changing both relations from < to <=

This is because I have also constraints which ensures <. Thus, even though relaxed them to <=, < will be still be enforced.

@A.Omidi, thank you for asking
